# How do I open a list of pages automatically and sequentially?

Tags: javascript, web, greasemonkey, sequential

I wish to load a list of webpages sequentially, with Greasemonkey.

```
var list = array ('http://www.google.com', 'site2', 'site3', 'site4');
window.location.href = list[0];
```

The script should work as follows: open site 1, wait 5 seconds, open site 2, wait 5 seconds, etc.

I don't know how to make the script open sites in sequence, maybe compare the actual URL to the list and move on the next one(?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[This approach, for Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11365844/331508), will also work in Greasemonkey.

Put your sites in an array, like that, but you must also set your [`@include`, `@exclude`, and `@match` directives](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40exclude) to fire on the appropriate sites.

Putting it all together, here's a **complete script**:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Multipage, MultiSite slideshow of sorts
// @include     http://google.com/*
// @include     http://site2/*
// @include     http://site3/*
// @include     http://site4/*
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a major design
    change introduced in GM 1.0.
    It restores the sandbox.
*/

var urlsToLoad  = [
    'http://google.com/'
    , 'http://site2/somepage/'
    , 'http://site3/somepage/'
    , 'http://site4/somepage/'
];

/*--- Since many of these sites load large pictures, Chrome's and 
    Firefox's injection may fire a good deal before the image(s) 
    finish loading.
    So, insure script fires after load:
*/
window.addEventListener ("load", FireTimer, false);
if (document.readyState == "complete") {
    FireTimer ();
}
//--- Catch new pages loaded by WELL BEHAVED ajax.
window.addEventListener ("hashchange", FireTimer,  false);

function FireTimer () {
    setTimeout (GotoNextURL, 5000); // 5000 == 5 seconds
}

function GotoNextURL () {
    var numUrls     = urlsToLoad.length;
    var urlIdx      = urlsToLoad.indexOf (location.href);
    urlIdx++;
    if (urlIdx >= numUrls)
        urlIdx = 0;

    location.href   = urlsToLoad[urlIdx];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your code. It works brillantly. Just another little question. Is there a way to force firefox to load from scratch a webpage even if is in the same domain? Because I've noticed that if I insert in the list 2 pages of the same website it stops working because it doens't fully reload the page and GM script is not executed anymore.

Comment: Give two, or more, specific URLs where this happens.  Are they different only by anchors or hashtags?

Comment: Updated the script to handle "new" pages loaded by **WELL BEHAVED** AJAX.  If that doesn't fix it for you, please open a new question and provide exact URL's of the problem pages.

Answer (score 1):

Two ways I can think of for doing this are:

Using [`gm_getvalue`](http://greasemonkey.win-start.de/advanced/gm_getvalue.html), `gm_setvalue` to retrieve, store the index of current site in `list` to Greasemonkey's persistent memory.

Or, using something like:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    window.location.href = (list.length > list.indexOf(window.location.href)) ? list[list.indexOf(window.location.href)+1] : list[0];
},5000)
```