# Scriptish script needs the page refreshed to run?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, scriptish

This script assists in a checkout process at an online store. All is working correctly, except the need to refresh the page to get the program to run initially.

I wonder if it is a cache problem because it works on other products that have been previously viewed. I also tried tinkering with the `@run-at` to no avail. I'm using the *Scriptish* extension and it is a standalone `.js` file.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @id             proper-id
// @name           proper-name
// @version        1.0
// @namespace      
// @description    
// @include        proper-url-here
// @include about:blank
// @run-at window-load
// ==/UserScript==

for (var i=0; i<document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0].length; i++){
    if(document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0].options[i].text == 11) {
        document.getElementsByName("skuAndSize")[0].selectedIndex = i;
    }
}
document.getElementsByClassName("button-container add-to-cart")[0].click();
```

Why does this userscript only run on refresh?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a classic problem with pages that change their content via AJAX.
`@run-at` has no effect because the targeted content is loaded long after the window `load` event. And, "new" pages are really complete rewrites via AJAX -- until you refresh the page, at least.

Change the script to `@run-at document-end` (or omit the line) and then, depending on the target page and how you are using it, it may be enough to fire off of `hashchange` as shown on ["I have to refresh the page for my Greasemonkey script to run?"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14024120/331508) or as shown on [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12261238/331508).

The go to tool is [`waitForKeyElements`<sup>More info</sup>](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508), however.   Your script might be as simple as:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

waitForKeyElements ("[name='skuAndSize']", setSizeIndex);
waitForKeyElements (".button-container.add-to-cart", clickAddToCart);

function setSizeIndex (jNode) {
    var node    = jNode[0];
    for (var J = node.options.length - 1;  J >= 0;  --J) {
        if (node.options[J].text == "11") {
            node.selectedIndex = J;
            break;
        }
    }
}

function clickAddToCart (jNode) {
    var clickEvent  = document.createEvent ('MouseEvents');
    clickEvent.initEvent ('click', true, true);
    jNode[0].dispatchEvent (clickEvent);
}
```

See, also, ["Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048223/331508).

Comment: Thanks man! This worked like a charm; a great description and all to boot. =) I should've just went with jQuery. I was also thinking that something along the lines of an addEventListener() could be implemented to get the functionality up to par. Thanks again!