# Loading sequential web pages in a browser

Tags: javascript, browser, greasemonkey, sequential

I can't find anything that meets my needs here but hopefully someone will have a simple answer.

I want my browser to load pages one after the other, i.e. `www.sitename.com/page 0405`, then `www.sitename.com/page 0406` etc, with a variable interval.

I don't need it to do anything other than the above. I just want it to visit each sequentially-numbered page in succession.

Comment: See, also, ["How to open a list of pages automatically and sequentially?"](http://stackoverflow.com/q/12260455/331508).

Comment: The url you marked it as duplicate of (your own answer) is not really the same.

Comment: I'll admit that I know nothing about scripts, but the "Greasemonkey fetch values" suggestion seems to have nothing to do with what I've asked.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know enough to know if there's elements I can use from that script. I just wanted a little package that I could set the parameters for, and let it run.

Comment: @eoghie, try this: http://pastebin.com/ujPX0h5V - create a new html page with this script in its body, set the variables as per your requirements, and visit the page you just created. Should open all your pages in tabs.

Comment: @Sidd I think this is perfect - first try and it worked exactly as I hoped - thanks so much for this. Can I give a +1 somewhere for your help?

Answer (score 1):

`onload` is triggered when an element loads. Just put an iframe and load the next page every time onload triggers.

```
var i = 0
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe')
iframe.onload = function() {
  iframe.src = 'http://www.sitename.com/page'+i
  i++
}
iframe.onload()
```