# Javascript - how to randomly redirect to websites without repeating?

Tags: javascript, redirect, web

I'd like to make a tampermonkey script that randomly redirects to websites without repeating. Once all the websites have been viewed, I want there to be an alert that notifies that the script is finished.

I've used the script from here ([How to redirect to one out of given set of sites?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346639/how-to-redirect-to-one-out-of-given-set-of-sites/11365844#11365844)) but it repeats the websites.

How should I go about with this?

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Cat slideshow
// @match       https://i.imgur.com/homOZTh.jpg
// @match       https://i.imgur.com/NMDCQtA.jpg
// @match       https://i.imgur.com/iqm9LoG.jpg
// ==/UserScript==

var urlsToLoad  = [
    'https://i.imgur.com/homOZTh.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/NMDCQtA.jpg',
    'https://i.imgur.com/iqm9LoG.jpg',
];

setTimeout (GotoRandomURL, 4000);

function GotoRandomURL () {
    var numUrls     = urlsToLoad.length;
    var urlIdx      = urlsToLoad.indexOf (location.href);
    if (urlIdx >= 0) {
        urlsToLoad.splice (urlIdx, 1);
        numUrls--;
    }

    urlIdx          = Math.floor (Math.random () * numUrls);
    location.href   = urlsToLoad[urlIdx];
}
```

Comment: Please accept my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: fixed the math.random section of the code.

This should work. I'm just making a copy of the array and then after navigating to the url I remove that url from the copied array. It will only repeat a url after it has gone through all urls and started over.

```
const urlsToLoad = [
  'https://i.imgur.com/homOZTh.jpg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/NMDCQtA.jpg',
  'https://i.imgur.com/iqm9LoG.jpg',
];

let copyOfUrlsToLoad = [];

setTimeout(goToRandomURL, 4000);

function goToRandomURL () {
  if (copyOfUrlsToLoad.length === 0) {
    copyOfUrlsToLoad = urlsToLoad;
  }
  urlIdx = getRandomInt(0, copyOfUrlsToLoad.length);
  location.href = copyOfUrlsToLoad[urlIdx];
  copyOfUrlsToLoad.splice(urlIdx, 1);
}

// This function comes from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random#Getting_a_random_integer_between_two_values
function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(min);
    max = Math.floor(max);
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min)) + min; //The maximum is exclusive and the minimum is inclusive
}
```

If you want to open the url in a new tab or window, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5141926/2555516) says to replace the `location.href` line with the following:

`window.open(copyOfUrlsToLoad[urlIdx], '_blank');`

Comment: how does this maintain a seen/unseen page rollover? (i see no persistence)

Comment: Oops :\ It doesn't. I guess I missed that part of the question. I don't have any experience with tampermonkey scripts. But hopefully the code I wrote can still help out.